# Delete an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

Looking to delete an object in Django, but none of the other Stack Overflow questions fix my issue.  Looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124658/deleting-objects-in-django), but it doesn't seem to be working.  My delete object code (in the views file) looks like this:

```py
@login_required
def delete_entry(request, entry_id):
    """Delete an existing entry."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.delete(commit=False) ### Code to delete object
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

And in URLs.py:

```py
path('delete_entry/<int:entry_id>', views.delete_entry, name='delete_entry'),
```

I would like to use a [Bootstrap 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) button (inside a modal) to delete the entry (so without any redirects to another confirmation page),

[image: Screenshot]

Unfortunately, this isn't working.  I'm just getting a server error saying that `NoReverseMatch at /delete_entry/6`.

Using Python `3`.

Comment: Re *"URLs.py"*: Isn't that normally *"[urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639590/where-does-my-urls-py-file-go-in-my-django-project)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was following a tutorial where the filename was `URLs.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to call the delete method on the form. If you want to delete the object, you should call it on the object:

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=entry_id) # Retrieve the object with the specified id
my_object.delete() # Delete it
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects) is the relevant Django documentation.

I think that you're looking for a [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview).

Comment: Would I put this code inside the "if request.method != 'post'" or the else block? Sorry for being so clueless! I'm new to Django.

Comment: You can put it anywhere, use the entry_id parameter you pass to your view to retrieve the object you want to delete and use the .delete() method to delete it. Or use DeleteView like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531258/example-of-django-class-based-deleteview